# What's the name of this humanist sans-serif font used for the Anthony Chabot Regional Park signage?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I'm developing an app, and I would like to use this font:

[image]

Does anybody know what it is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cannot see the fine details to be sure whether it's [Helvetica](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/helvetica/) or [Helvetica Neue](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/) but I'm inclining to the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a link to the exact page you would like to identify the font from (vs. an image)?

You can use a browser plugin such as WhatFont in Google Chrome to identify not only the exact font, but the font stack used on the page and the font attributes.

---

Edit: There is a website version http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/